# How many different orders are possible in which the key values can occur while searching for a particular key?

Tags: binary-search-tree

When searching for the key value 60 in a binary search tree, nodes containing the key values 10, 20, 40, 50, 70, 80, 90 are
traversed, not necessarily in the order given. How many different orders are possible in which these key values can occur on the
search path from the root node containing the value 60?

Comment: Just adding to Somesh answer. It can be 7C3 as well. Since the greater group 90, 80, 70 can be positioned in 7C3 ways and for each combination only one unique position is for the smaller keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is 7C4.

Searching for 60, we encounter 4 keys less than 60 (10,20,40,50) & 3 keys greater (70,80,90).

The four lesser keys must appear in ascending order while the three greater ones must appear in descending order otherwise some keys will be left out in the traversal.

Note that in the traversal, these lesser keys might not be continuous and can be separated by greater keys.

For eg: 10, 90, 20, 30, 80, 40, 70, 50

but the order of both groups of keys (lesser and greater) remains the same individually.

Now, out of total seven positions, the lesser keys acquire four positions which can be selected in 7C4 ways. Once we know the places of these four keys, the places of the three greater keys only have one permutation.

For eg: if we know that

10, _, 20, 30, _, 40, _, 50

Then there's only one permutation of places for 90, 80 & 70 which is place number 2, 5 & 7 respectively.

Therefore for each combination of lesser keys, there's a unique combination of greater keys.

So total combinations= 7C4*1
=35 ways